# Infinitive and use of "dass" in a sentence

Tags: infinitive, comparative

Is this sentence grammaticality correct?

"Denkst du dass, es besser ist, allein zu sein als zusammen zu sein?"

Or is it better to say;

"Denkst du, allein zu sein ist besser als zusammen zu sein?"

Comment: This is not what the question is about, but saying *zusammen sein* without *mit jemandem* sounds awkward to me.

Answer (score 6):

I would say

> "Denkst du, dass es besser ist, allein zu sein, als zusammen?"
>   (notice that the comma comes before *dass*)

or

> "Denkst du, allein zu sein ist besser als zusammen?"

Both are equally good. The important part is that "zu sein" is only used once, you'd only use a second infinitive it it were a different one:

> "Denkst du, allein zu sein ist besser als zusammen zu leben?"